# Copy to Output Directory files placed in project-specific subdirectory

Tags: tfs

I have a Solution file with several database projects. I have scheduled a nightly build in TFS. This works fine. Dacpacs are created in output directory and also the copy-Always files are copied.

My problem is that all the files that have "Copy to Output Dicetory = Copy always" are copied to the same drop directory (as specified in the Build Defaults).
I would like the output files to be placed in a subdirectory that is specific for the Project (with the same name as Project would be fine).. is that possible?

EDIT:

I found this (Edit build definition):

Process -> 5. Advanced -> MSBuild Arguments: /p:GenerateProjectSpecificOutputFolder=true

This will create one subdirectory per project!

I'll leave my question here in case anyone else has use for it.